# Vue : Filter on array of object for search

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, vue.js

I have an array having three objects and each object have straight key value pair.

```
 // Search Input
 <div class="dv-header-search">
    <input type="text" class="dv-header-input"
      placeholder="Search"
      v-model="query.search_input">
  </div>

//Table row
<tr v-for="row in filteredRow">
    <td v-for="(value, key) in row">{{value}}</td>
</tr>

data() {
  return {
    model: {},
    columns: {},
    query: {
      search_input: ''
    },
  }
},

// Setting model after API call
.then(function(response) {
    Vue.set(vm.$data, 'model', response.data.model)
})

computed: {
  filteredRow: function(){
    return this.model.data.filter((row) => {
      return row;
    });
  }
}
```

It gives me the following exception :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

What Am i missing here.

Comment: Where is the `model `definition?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy added to the question code.

Comment: @ohgodwhy question updated

Comment: Can you please show us exactly what the data in `model` looks like?

Comment: You define `model` as an empty object in your `data` method. So `this.model.data` is going to be `undefined`. So in your `filteredRow` computed, `this.model.data.filter` is what's throwing the error.

Comment: @thanksd I have updated my question code, The `model` is setting after an api call.

Comment: @ohgodwhy i have updated the question code.

Comment: it's exactly as @thanksd has said. Just define `model: { data: [] }` and on page load you won't have that error anymore. The promise object is not resolving in time. Alternatively, you can use a `v-if="model.data !== undefined"` if you'd rather have the template handle it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You define `model` as an empty object in your `data` method.

Even if you are setting the value of `model` later, your `filteredRow` method will fire when the component renders the template, meaning `this.model.data` will be `undefined` at that point.

The simplest fix would be to give `model.data` an initial value in the `data` method:

```
data() {
  return {
    model: { data: [] },
    columns: {},
    query: {
      search_input: ''
    },
  }
},
```

Comment: Fixed, Awesome. A quick one @thanksd, Search is not working. It should be working with that fix ?

Comment: That's a very broad question and probably deserves a separate post including a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue you're having

Comment: Yeah sure, Thanks :)